Fake or legit trading platoforms?
I've recently been introduced to the below site to conduct smart contracts.
Does anyone know if these are legit or if I have entered something sketchy.
I went from trust wallet and entered the 2nd site to enter Eth Universe.
The 1st site seems to be my wallet I'm that platform.
My funds have recently been frozen and the platform support has requested that I input 100% of the current balance and a penalty for possible fraud account. Then if no suspicious activity, they amount is released back for trading.
https://www.euhundlemeyi.top
https://www.eutreandiz.com
Any help in deciding if this is legit or scam?

First link is looks like a coinbase wallet phishing scam. Second doesn't load for me but redirects to a page hosted at the first so would expect it to be a scam. The redirect url looks like it goes to open an "exchange wallet", so guessing that is what you connected to.

Thank you. I am thinking it may be what you explained. Thank you for replying - this is also tied to the other question I had about them freezing funds and asking for 100% pay as a penalty. Seems I may have gotten into a 3rd party URL.

Would need more details to say. Used to work at a dex and experienced a lot of users clicking fake links to sites that performed similar to what you describe. There would some person, who would ask for more money to get access to what was already lost. The initial deposits would be direct transfers to wallets (not smart contracts), and there wouldn't any way to get it back (aside from hoping they deposit to a cex like coinbase and it gets frozen by the police). If you have the transactions from interacting with them, I will to take a look.

What do you mean the transactions? I still have access to the platform. I'm still 50/50 on if it's a scam or not. The request to deposit 100% of the balance is what has me weirded out.

Have you ever been able to cash out?
For the transaction, you said "I've recently been introduced to the below site to conduct smart contracts". interacting with smart contracts would require a transaction. As would transferring coins/tokens. How do you deposit there?

I have pulled out before. I went from coinbase to Trust wallet to Dapp URL I sent. Are you referencing a Hash? Keep in mind this was my first dabble with trades so I've never really looked this much into it.
